# boto ses connection error in django webapp

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-ses

I get following error on making ses connection in my django web application. Error occurs oin production server web app only.  Boto ses connection is working fine on python shell in production server and also in development server. I am struggling to find solution. Please help me.

Boto version is 2.38.0

```
boto [DEBUG]:Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
boto [ERROR]:Caught exception reading instance data
[error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/utils.py",     line 210, in retry_url
[error]     r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
[error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
[error]     response = meth(req, response)
[error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
[error]     'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
[error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
[error]     return self._call_chain(*args)
[error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
[error]     result = func(*args)
[error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
[error]     raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
[error] HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
[error] 2015-12-08 19:08:18,719 boto [ERROR]:Unable to read instance data, giving up
[error] <type 'exceptions.Exception'> No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV3Handler'] Check your credentials
```